# Why TreeView becomes recursive when it displays Regex matches?

Tags: regex, wpf, recursion, treeview, datatemplate

I tried to make app for testing regular expression

by using TreeView to display MatchCollection to window

But it does not work correctly

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="RegularExpressionTester.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RegularExpressionTester"
         xmlns:Regex="clr-namespace:System.Text.RegularExpressions;assembly=System"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <local:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Regex:Match}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Groups}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat=[{0}](Match)}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Regex:Group}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Captures}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat=[{0}](Group)}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Regex:Capture}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat=[{0}](Capture)}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Result:

[image: Real Application]

I want to display like this (expected result)

▶ Match

..▶ Group

....▶ Capture

▶ Match

..▶ Group

....▶ Capture

How I can do?

Comment: _But it not work correctly_ does not explain what the problem is? Can you give more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**why is it possible to get infinite hierarhy?**

it is due to structure of `Match.Groups` and `Group.Captures`

> The Match instance itself is equivalent to the first object in the collection, at Match.Groups[0]

from [Match class - Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4)

> the Group instance is equivalent to the last item of the collection returned by the Captures property, which reflects the last capture made by the capturing group

from [Group class - Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4)

**how to fix?**

modify Templates like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Regex:Match}"  
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Groups}">

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat=[{0}](Match)}"/>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Regex:Group}"  
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Captures}">
                
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat=[{0}](Group)}"/>
                
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Regex:Capture}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat=[{0}](Capture)}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: It work. But something different. Seem to Match casted to Group. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3EmLCf3GeuUYTh3ZXFvcWpTVW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Finally i use IValueConverter. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3EmLCf3GeuUTWhoYW1VS1FBbGM/view?usp=sharing & https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3EmLCf3GeuUd3R0SjRxN0k4THc/view?usp=sharing  Tanks for your help :)